# Handle method variable that is created by model class with Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to make Junit and Mockito test of my code. I have a variable that is a list created by user.class model. I have an idea how to mock the part on the right side of the equality sign, but I cant figure it out how to handle the left part.
My question is, how should I mock that User.class that is used to create the user variable list?

This is the variable I should handle:

```
List<User> user = daoUser.get(userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a unit test for the `daoUser.get(userID)` method, then you only need to mock any further methods that are contained in it. For example, if `daoUser.get(userID)`method has a `fooClass.doSomethingElse()` method in it, then you would mock the `FooClass`. Otherwise just create a unit test that compares the actual method output with a predefined expected value `List<User> expectedList`.

If you are trying to test another method and want to mock `daoUser.get(userID)`, then mock the `DaoUser` class and write a Mockito when statement, for example, `when(daoUser.get(anyString()).thenReturn(fooList)` so when the method you are testing hits `daoUser.get(userID)` then it doesn't actually call it but mocks the response instead.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In short, I want to test the class with my business logic. The variable from the question is in one of the methods. I'm doing exactly what you suggested in your second paragraph: 
`when(daoUser.get(Integer.parseInt(userInputInfo.get("townId")))).thenReturn(listOfUsers);`  where `listOfUsers` is predefined Map I created for the test. My concern is that `List<User> user` depends on User.class to be crated. User.class is model. Мy question is how to approach a variable that uses another class to be defined when testing? What is the right way?

Comment: @Hristo.L I would just create let's say 2 users like `User user1 = new User()` and `User user2 = new User()`. Then maybe set some values if you need and add them to a new list that you would return in the mock.